# React-Native Semi-Circle View

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm trying to figure out how to draw a semi-circle component. It might not even be possible in pure React, but I'm willing to try using a library. I looked around and couldn't find one that seemed to be what I'm looking for.

But rendering a circle is easy enough. In this example, I've got a circle rendering inside of another circle:

```js
    <View
      style={{
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        borderRadius: 300,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "darkred",
      }}
    >
      <View
        style={{
          width: "90%",
          height: "90%",
          borderRadius: 300,
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          backgroundColor: "red",
        }}
      ></View>
    </View>
```

The code above renders as the circle on the left (below), but I want to be able to do something similar to the circle on the right (forgive the poor editing skills) where I can render a semi-circle at any particular arc.

[image: Desired semi-circle]

Comment: I tried a different Google search and found this library: https://github.com/atull/react-native-shape but it looks like it hasn't been updated in over two years.

Comment: I would try doing it using svg (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg)

Comment: Seems better than anything I've found so far, I'll mess around with that.

Answer (score 0):

As proposed by @Freddy, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-svg has the tools that I need to accomplish this. I also used this as a guide, even though I needed to tweak a few things: https://sparkbox.com/foundry/how_to_code_an_SVG_pie_chart